# why can't I get a prime number using this python file?

Tags: python, math

I am a beginner of python, and I was doing a problem on project euler that asks me to find largest prime number. But my code did not work as I expected, and the number I got was not a prime number.Though working on this for a long time, I still could not find the problem. my code is

```
def is_prime(x):
  for i in range(2,x):
    if x%i==0:
        return False
    else:
        return True
def largest_prime_factor(x):
  a=range(1,x)
  list1=[]
  for i in a:
    if x%i==0 and is_prime(i) == True:
        list1.append(i)
  print max(list1)
```

anybody here can tell me why my code is wrong ? thanks u in advance

Answer (score 2):

There are *three* errors in your code. One, was already pointed out: you should `return True` at the end of the loop in `is_prime`. An other one is that `1` is not prime:

```
def is_prime(x):
   if x == 1:
       # 1 is not prime!
       return False

   # you can loop up to ceil(sqrt(x)) instead of all the way up to x
   for i in range(2, int(x**.5) + 1):
      if x%i==0:
          return False
      elif i > x:
          break   
   return True
```

The other is that `largest_prime_factor` is raising an error for prime numbers:

```
In [7]: largest_prime_factor(7)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-eceaf4811bfe> in <module>()
----> 1 largest_prime_factor(7)

<ipython-input-6-d40692628493> in largest_prime_factor(x)
     12     if x%i==0 and is_prime(i):
     13         list1.append(i)
---> 14   return max(list1)

ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

(Or returns `1` if you use the incorrect version of `is_prime` that considers `1` a prime number)

The problem is that `range(1, x)` doesn't contain `x`. So the loop in `largest_prime_factor`, when `x` is prime, will not be able to add `x` as factor. You should loop over a range that contains `x`:

```
def largest_prime_factor(x):
    list1=[]
    for i in range(1, x+1):
       if x%i==0 and is_prime(i):
           list1.append(i)
    return max(list1)
```

However this is quite inefficient. Instead you could loop up to `sqrt(x)` as in `is_prime`, but when you find a factor you divide `x`:

```
from itertools import chain

def largest_prime_factor(x):
    factors = []
    for div in chain([2], range(3, int(x**.5) + 1, 2)):
        while x % div == 0:
            factors.append(div)
            x //= div
        if div > x:
            break
    if x != 1:
        # return x   # should be okay to do this because x was prime
        factors.append(x)
    return max(factors)
```

This is more efficient because it has to loop only up to `sqrt(x)`, and returns the correct result:

```
In [11]: largest_prime_factor(7)
Out[11]: 7
```

Comment: `range` of the for is computed first and then `x` is reduced for each factor found. This means for example that `768 = 2**8 * 3` would find `2`, reduce `x` to 3 and then loop up to 28 (i.e. 768**0.5) while looking for divisors of 3...

Comment: @6502 Fixed it. Although it doesn't really change much... with big inputs it still takes too much time to factorize and it's better to use probabilistic algorithms to find prime factors.

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies within your `is_prime(x)`. It returns on the first instance of the function call. So instead of returning `True` or `False`, you might want to store it as a boolean or do some return logic. It could look something like this:

```
if x%i==0:
    continue
else:
    return False
```

Then return `True` at the end of the function if it reaches there.

Answer (score 0):

In the loop one should only return false, return true when ALL steps where tried.

```
def is_prime(x):
  for i in range(2,x):
    if x%i==0:
        return False   
  return True

def largest_prime_factor(x):
  a=range(1,x)
  list1=[]
  for i in a:
    if is_prime(i):
        list1.append(i)
  print max(list1)
```

Comment: @Bakuriu I just corrected, removing `x%i==0` - which more seemed an attempt to "correct" is_prime, a bug-squared (negative*negative=positive).

Comment: No you didn't correct it. `is_prime` is still wrong because `is_prime(1) -> True` and as it stands `largest_prime_factor` returns the biggest "prime" in the range `[1, x)` indipendently if it was a factor of `x` or not. See my answer for the full fixes.